# How can I get a music player to watch a folder for new files?

Tags: downloads, music, music-player, youtube-dl

I am using `youtube-dl` to download a series of short audio files. How can I set up a common music player [1] to monitor a given folder for new files and add them to the current playlist?

[1] Rhythmbox, Totem, VLC, or anything available in the 14.04 repos and usable in Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Rhythmbox using an "Automatic Playlist" and using the path variable.

[image: automatic playlist creation options window]

1. Create a directory named "youtube-dl" in ~/Music for youtube-dl to output files into. (in my testing, Rhythmbox wouldn't add files outside ~/Music for some reason).
2. Open Rhythmbox and create a new Automatic Playlist by clicking the "+" at bottom left below the playlists.
3. For the playlist variables set "Path", "contains", and "youtube-dl",
   then click "New" to finish.

Now Rhythmbox will add and remove audio tracks from this directory automatically.